# Angular PWA in ASP.Net Core Server - Serviceworker-Cache not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I created a Angular PWA and moved it into a ASP.Net Core Spa - Application. I can run it offline when served and installed via "npm http-server".

When I run it in the ASP.Net Server the Serviceworker loads with an error "Cannot read property 'put' of undefined" in ngsw-worker.js:

```
        write(key, value) {
          return this.cache.put(this.request(key), this.adapter.newResponse(JSON.stringify(value)));
        }
```

[image]

I am trying to cache requests from the webapi and configured them in the ngsw-config.json - file

```
    {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
      "index": "/index.html",
      "dataGroups": [
        {
          "name": "api-freshness",
          "urls": [
            "/odata/**"
          ],
          "cacheConfig": {
            "strategy": "freshness",
            "maxSize": 500,
            "maxAge": "3d",
            "timeout": "2s"
          }
        }
      ],
      "assetGroups": [
        {
          "name": "app",
          "installMode": "prefetch",
          "resources": {
            "files": [
              "/favicon.ico",
              "/index.html",
              "/*.css",
              "/*.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "assets",
          "installMode": "lazy",
          "updateMode": "prefetch",
          "resources": {
            "files": [
              "/assets/**",
              "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

In the first place the manifest.webmanifest file was served with wrong content-type, so I added a provider in my startup.cs. But this didn't help.

```
        provider.Mappings[".webmanifest"] = "application/manifest+json";

        app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() {
            ContentTypeProvider = provider
        });
```

Comment: Why do you need this line ? `provider.Mappings[".webmanifest"] = "application/manifest+json";`

Comment: Because ASP.Net core serves the manifest file with the wrong content type (text/html)

Comment: The manifest file has nothing to do with service worker caching. You can register a service worker and cache without a manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the chrome browser which is used from Visual Studio in the debugging mode causes the issue. The serviceworker doesn't get proberly registered when I launch the browser from VS. The error disappears when I copy the URL and paste it to a new instance of chrome.

Also the caching worked after I used the the "clear site data" - button in the "Clear storage" tab.

Comment: I've been struggling to get my Angular 8 .NET Core 2.2 project in Visual Studio to run as a PWA. I can get a basic angular PWA app running using the CLI and http-server but I can't figure out how to get my .NET Core project to work. Any articles or links that would help would be much appreciated. A sample project would be even better!